# SQL - Subquery returned more than 1 value. Which one?

Tags: sql, select, stored-procedures

in the project I'm currently working on there is a number of stored procedures. 
Report generator used one of them, but now it does not work. Manual execution returns an error:

> [21000][512] Subquery returned more than 1 value.  This is illegal
>   when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=, or when the subquery
>   is used as an expression.

I don't have much experience in SQL and it will take too long to understand how this procedure works (it is about 2000 lines). Is there any way to get a verbose description of the error to understand which line of stored proc reported it?
Or is there any pattern to search for, which will decrease the area of search, like:

```
... = SELECT ( ...
```

Thank you

Comment: Search for `SELECT ..., (SELECT .... FROM... ) FROM` and `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE col = (SELECT ... FROM ...)`. *Do not use workaround like `TOP 1 or LIMIT 1`* First try to understand the query and try to rewrite it without scalar subquery using `JOIN/CASE/...`. The fastest way to find it can be using search/find and `(<anywhitespace_regex>SELECT`

Comment: I will not use TOP 1 / LIMIT 1 in any case as they might hide the errors. Most probably I even won't modify the stored proc - it worked well for years. The issue should be in incorrect set up of some data in database, and I'm trying to get which data broke the query.

Comment: If you need debugging help then use Print before every select so you know where it stops